# How do I make ESC clear a line in Bash Under Windows instead of Ctrl+u?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, cygwin, key-binding

I use bash in Windows, both in Cygwin and in Git Bash (part of Git for Windows). In bash unlike in the Windows `cmd.exe` <kbd>Esc</kbd> does not clear the line, only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>. How can I make clear the line also?

Thanks!

Comment: You may find that the console will interfere with any attempt to resolve this.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.humbug.in/2010/custom-key-bindings-keyboard-shortcuts-in-bash/). If it works, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 14):

I don't have a Cygwin or Git for Windows install handy to test this, but here's the Unix answer:

Create a file in your (cygwin) home directory named ".inputrc", and add this line to it:

```
Escape: unix-line-discard
```

On my favorite Unix variant, Control-u is mapped to unix-line-discard, which deletes everything before the cursor. If you want it to delete the whole input line, including anything that may be to the right of the cursor, use "kill-whole-line" instead of "unix-line-discard".

Note that your bash line editing mode might eat the Escape. Bash on my system defaults to vi-style line editing mode (`set -o vi`), and as you may know, vi is all about the Escape key, so when I try this I have to hit Escape twice because the first one gets eaten by the vi-style editing mode. I'm not an emacs guy so I don't know what the emacs-style line editing mode will do with an Escape keypress.

Note also that the .inputrc file is read when the shell starts, so after editing your ~/.inputrc, close your shell and open a new one to see if the changes worked.

Comment: Awesome! Been trying to do this for a while on Mac OS X too. The point about the line editing mode helped tremendously because in the various attempts to get this to work I probably skipped right over a working solution because I was only hitting escape once.

Comment: I'm using git bash on Windows (MINGW64). Using `.inputrc` with `Escape: unix-line-discard` works - but it isn't _instant_ - when I press the `Esc` key it takes about 500ms for the line to be cleared. Any idea?

Comment: This is useful, but for me `Escape: kill-whole-line` works even better. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30991 .

Comment: @GarretWilson My answer already suggested that option for those who'd prefer it.

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't see it @Spiff , because you used quotes ("kill-whole-line") instead of code (`kill-whole-line`). I had so many tabs open and was quickly scanning so many posts at the same time that my eyes didn't catch it. 